# [C#][UWP] How to get full Cookiess of website HTTPS

Tags: uwp, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to get cookies of forum: https://forums.voz.vn/ with my Chrome browser.

I have 6 cookie values:

1. vfimloggedin.
2. vflastactivity.
3. vflastvisit.
4. vfpassword.
5. vfsessionhash
6. vfuserid.

[image]

When I use code below:

```
string postData = "&vb_login_username="
            + user
            + "&vb_login_password="
            + password
            + "&cookieuser=checked"
            + "&do=login"
            + "&s="
            + "securitytoken=guest"
            + "&vb_login_md5password="
            + "&vb_login_md5password_utf=&";
        string applicationEncoded = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Resource.USER_AGENT, Resource.USER_AGENT_VALUE);

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(loginUrl, new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, applicationEncoded)).Result)
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync("https://forums.voz.vn/").Result)
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = responseMessage.Content)
                    {
                        contentHtml = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                        IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(new Uri("https://forums.voz.vn/")).Cast<Cookie>();
                        foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
                        {
                            if (cookie.Name == Resource.COOKIES_NAME)
                            {
                                appSetting.Cookies = cookie.Value;
                                break;
                            }                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            contentHtml = Resource.STR_ERROR;
        }
```

I saw 4 cookies values:

1. vfimloggedin.
2. vflastactivity.
3. vflastvisit.
4. vfsessionhash

[image]

How can I retrieve all cookies for this forum?

Thanks!

Comment: Did u know when these cookies are saved? I suggested that you first use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to simulate HTTP post request and to see when and which cookie is stored. I guessed your 'Login' HTPP POST request failed, then the remaining two cookies are not sent from server to your computer.

Comment: ---  I suggested that you first use fiddler to simulate HTTP post request and to see when and which cookie is stored--
-> Thank for suggested, i'll try this.
--- I guessed your 'Login' HTPP POST request failed, then the remaining two cookies are not sent from server to your computer---
I dont think that, because when im add vfsessionhash cookies to HttpClient, html response have infomation of this account.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!

There was an error in my submit form. I checked with the fiddler and discovered it.